# Letting people update slides without edit access?

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

I've set up a datawarehouse and data pipeline for a financial firm. There's a bunch of financial KPIs getting updated now every day in a google sheet through the BQ connector, which is in turn linked to a slide.

I have two issues however. Firstly, Finance people love pretty slides, so the linked table has to have the padding removed so it fits neatly on the page. Sadly, when I remove the padding in the slide, any color coding changes in the sheet won't transfer over. Given the sheet has some conditional formatting, that's an issue.

Secondly, the numbers only update when I click to update the Linked Objects. There's hundreds of people looking at the slides, so I don't want to give them edit access (so they won't fuck anything up), but I would like to have the slides get updated without me having to go in and click update. Does anyone know how to update the objects on a schedule or after an input?

Huge thanks in advance, I'm at my wits end here.

I dug through the Slides menus but could not see any option to do so. I also couldn't find an option to remove cell padding already in Google Sheets (like you can do in Excel).